# Bash scripting to login to VPN automatically

Tags: linux, bash, vpn, openvpn

I am very new to Bash scripting, and am trying to log in to my school's VPN server using my Raspberry Pi.

All I have right now is a file called `login.sh`, which has this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo openconnect vpn.ucr.edu/engineering
```

So I get this to run to get onto the VPN server but after that it asks on the terminal:

> Please enter username and password.
>   Username:

I am confused on how to get it to take my user name automatically, without me manually typing it in. I would also want to do the same thing to automatically enter my password.

How can I write a Bash script that will input the user name and password automatically?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to automate the process of logging into the VPN with a bash script. Food for thought, this a security hole that you shouldn't be looking to go down. From http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/078: *"Passwords were never intended to be put into programs, or generated by programs. They were intended to be entered only by the fingers of an actual human being, with a functional brain, and never, ever written down anywhere."*

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I connect to my VPN server using bash "here document". Place your connection data instead of VPN_GROUP, USERNAME and PASSWORD (your server may or may not use VPN group).

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo openconnect --no-dtls --interface=sslvpn https://vpn_site <<EOF
VPN_GROUP
USERNAME
PASSWORD
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect script to launch the process and write to the stdin

Comment: where do I learn this exactly I just had a friend tell me to use expect but I dont know where to start.